# In a local variable declaration statement, inside of a block statment, which part of the declaration statement is the declarator?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

14.4.1. Local Variable Declarators and Types

Each declarator in a local variable declaration declares one local variable, whose name is the Identifier that appears in the declarator.

```
{  
     int x = 10;
}
```

Which part of local variable declaration statement is is the declarator?

Comment: I must say that I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have added more context to the question, by adding more information to it, this should help in understanding the question.

Comment: Based in the link, `x` would be the declarator, `int` would be the type, and `= 10` would be the initialization. You could have more than 1 declarator by coding `int x, y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you were looking at:

```
LocalVariableDeclaration:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators
```

In other words, the declarator is the declared name and optional initializer: `x = 10`.